# Using multiple intents in same Activity

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use an intent to import a file form the device to my app. I am using `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);`

My question is... I know for the intent I need to have `onActivityResult()` method, but I already have one for another intent being used the the class, is there a way I can have two `onActivityResult()` methods for two intents.

Answer (score 1):

onActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)

use differnet requestCode for different intents

Comment: ...do I need to change method name? Do I need @override? Thanks

Comment: you should add the @override annotation above the function name. What do you mean by change method name?

Answer (score 0):

```
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCodeForIntentOne);
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCodeForIntentTwo);
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if(requestCode==requestForIntentOne)
    {}
    if(requestCode==requestForIntentTwo)
    {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you call startActivityForResult(), you supply a requestCode.  That will match the value of the same name you get in onActivityResult()

So you can do :

```
if (requestCode == requestCodeA) {
 //handle case 1
} else if (requestCode == requestCodeB) {
 //handle case 1
}
```